# Should "noun" be plural here?

Tags: grammaticality, grammatical-number

Should I use "a noun" or "nouns" in this sentence?

> We use any before ***nouns*** to refer to indefinite or unknown
>   quantities or an unlimited entity.

Or:

> We use any before ***a noun*** to refer to indefinite or unknown
>   quantities or an unlimited entity.

Comment: Your sentences do not make sense as they stand.  Are you trying to say "We use [the word] *'any'* before [a] noun[s] ..."?  I think I know what you are trying to say in the sentence(s), but you cannot just you *'any'* before **any** noun (which is what you seem to be implying) - you can use it only before some nouns and in some contexts.  I'm assuming that you are learning English, in which case you questions are probably more suited to our sister site [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/).  As regards your actual question (as I understand it), either form is possible.

Comment: Yes. (They are both correct.) Which you use depends on what you're trying to express.

Comment: @JasonBassford Both express the same ideas. Therefore, as long as they want to express the rule that "any" is used before an arbitrary noun to do what the predicate says, there is no other dependence for the choice between those two alternatives.

Comment: @user647486 But if you're saying they both express the *identical* thing, then there is no point in discussing it. Instead, flip a coin. What I mean is that the wording *does* make a difference—and that difference determines the word used.

Answer (score -1):

In English, sentences in present tense, indicative mood, with the subject quantified by an indefinite article, can often be understood as general truths.

> A dog wags its tail.

is a statement that is true when there exists some dog that wags its tail. However, this same sentence is also interpreted as saying that

> An arbitrary dog will wag its tail.

The indefinite article *a*, since it indicates that the noun *dog* is not identifiable to the listener, can be interpreted as *an arbitrary*.

The same happens when no article is used in front of a plural noun. The sentence

> Dogs wag their tails.

is true when there is a group of more than one dog that at that moment wagged their tails. However, it is also interpreted as

> All dogs wag their tails.

Actually, very likely people will find odd the first interpretation for such a short sentence, but using more specific predicates can make the first interpretation more feasible. For example,

> Dogs wag their tails in front of me.

Your sentences are but the same use of a plural without article or a singular with an indefinite article in a present indicative, to express a fact understood to be general. They are mildly ambiguous in both cases due to the lack of proper quantification, even though most English speakers would find unlikely interpreting them as non-general statements about the use of the word *any* before all nouns.